# What additional loaders do I need? (Module parse failed: Unexpected token (16:9))

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am using a library called `danfojs` and it gives me the following error when I compiled.

```
14:01:51.417    Failed to compile.
14:01:51.417    ./node_modules/danfojs/src/index.js 16:9
14:01:51.417    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (16:9)
14:01:51.418    File was processed with these loaders:
14:01:51.418     * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
14:01:51.418    You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
14:01:51.418    | export { Str } from "./core/strings";
14:01:51.418    | export { Utils } from "./core/utils";
14:01:51.418    > export * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
14:01:51.418    | export var _version = "0.2.5";
```

Seems like I need to set up some additional loader maybe with webpack settings, could any one point me out the right direction of how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should not import `/src/index.js` from that lib: that is apparently source code with ES6 features, not supported by current Node.